# VueJs - How to update bind value where :value="text"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**I am trying to update string on change inside a `textarea` but it does not work.**

## Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea :value="text" @change="changed = true" @keyup="changed = true"></textarea>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button @click.prevent="saveChanges">Save Changes</button>
      <button @click.prevent="discardChanges">Discard Changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Editor",
  props: ["fileText"],
  data() {
    return {
      changed: false,
      text: this.fileText,
      sendText: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getCurrentText() {
      return this.text;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitToParent() {
      this.$parent.$emit("custom-event", this.changed);
    },
    saveChanges() {
      if (this.changed) {
        console.log("I changed");
        this.sendText = this.getCurrentText;
        this.changed = false;
        this.$emit("close");
        console.log(this.sendText);
      } else {
        this.$emit("close");
      }
    },
    discardChanges() {
      this.text = this.fileText;
      this.$emit("close");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I proceed to make a change inside the text area, then click on the **Save Changes** button, `this.changed` is set to true, `console.log("I changed");` fires up, but `console.log(this.sendText);` returns the same, unmodified text.

As a whole, I am trying to edit text inside a file. The above component gets `fileText` from it's parent component and I would like to send back to the parent a text that has been modified (if it has been modified). Basically updating the text inside a file, if the text changes.

This is a raw version and will change accordinly.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-jackson-gfk3k?file=/src/App.vue)**

Instead of `:value="text"` try to use [`v-model="text"`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model)

Like this:

```html
<textarea v-model="text" @change="changed = true" @keyup="changed = true"></textarea>
```

Comment: do as like said by @artanik, you will get the result

Comment: It doesn't work as intended. `console.log(this.text);` return the updated text inside `saveChanges()`, but afterwards `this.text` returns to the value it gets from `props: ["fileText"],`.